# How to compute norm of vector-valued function in Sobolev Space H1?

Tags: analysis, sobolev-spaces, vector-fields

I need to compute the norm of the function $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ in the Sobolev space $H^1$.

Could somebody tell me if the following definition is correct? For example, for function $f$ given by $(x, y) \to (u, v)$

$$
\| f(x, y) \|_{H^1}^2 = \int |u|^2 + \int |v|^2 + \int |\partial_x u|^2 + \int |\partial_y u |^2 + \int |\partial_x v|^2 + \int |\partial_y v|^2.
$$

When I look at the textbooks, they always operate on functionals, that is, functions with range in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Do you mean $\|f(x,y)\|_{H^1}^{\color{red}2}$? Notice that all norms on a finite dimensional vector space ($\mathbb{R}^2$) are equivalent.

Comment: @WillieWong, yes, thanks, this is a typo